# Function returns before code finishes running in swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, closures

I made a class function which contains a closure that reverse geocodes location coordinates into a address string. I initially had it written in a viewcontroller, but I need to run this code in a few spots.

My problem is that the class function returns the string before the closure runs, so the returning string is blank. What are ways I can fix this? And are there better ways to organize my code rather than using a class function?

```
import CoreLocation
class LocationUtil: CLLocation {
    class func getLocationAddress(location:CLLocation?) -> NSString {
        var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        var addressString : String = ""

        if location != nil {
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
                var placemark:CLPlacemark!

                if error == nil && placemarks.count > 0 {
                    placemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark

                    if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
                        addressString = placemark.subThoroughfare + " "
                    }
                    if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placemark.thoroughfare + ", "
                    }
                    if placemark.locality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placemark.locality + ", "
                    }
                    if placemark.administrativeArea != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placemark.administrativeArea + " "
                    }
                    if placemark.postalCode != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placemark.postalCode + " "
                    }
                    if placemark.country != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placemark.country
                    }

                }
                println("Address in closure: \(addressString)") //prints addresss
            })
        }
        println("Address out of closure: \(addressString)") // doesn't print address
        return addressString //this returns nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation` runs *asynchronously* and calls the **`completionHandler`** only after it *completes*.

So, getting a return value is obviously not an option. Instead, accept  closure as an input/argument for your class function

```
class func getLocationAddress(location: CLLocation, getLocCompletionHandler : (addressString : String?, error : NSError?) -> Void) {

       geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
            //Your current code
            //...
            //...
            println("Address: \(addressString)")
            //Instead of returning the address string, call the 'getLocCompletionHandler'
            getLocCompletionHandler(addressString: addressString, error: error)

        })
}
```

And when you call this function, instead of working with the return value, wait for the closure to be called:

```
LocationUtil.getLocationAddress(currentLocation, completionHandler: { (addressObject, error) -> Void in
    println("Address: \(addressString)")
    //OR handle the error appropriately
}
```

Read up on [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) to get a better understanding of the concept.

As far as organisation of code goes, class function is a good choice in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to follow this and get it to work! Still working through my mental block on fully understanding closures.

Comment: Funny you should say you have a mental 'block' for closures.. closers are essentially like 'blocks' from ObjC

Answer (score 4):

You should return the `completionHandler` inside your

```
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
```

The `completionHandler` will be called when the function is finished. For this to work you should also make your own function return asynchronously.

This is needed because your `reverseGeocodeLocation` function is ran asynchronously. Your main thread will continue to run your `getLocationAddress` so it will return the string but it is empty because it is returned before the asynchronous function finished.